# How to assign a value to a cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to import a text file and process it in Excel.

First step is to split the data into 2 groups: Headers and content.

I have creates two worksheets. Then import text data. Then determine the Height, Width and number of items of the data file.

The issue comes trying to copy the headers data to one of the worksheets. I am getting no value.

I have tried assigning as value:

```
Worksheets("TIME").Range(Cells(j, k)).Value = Range(Cells(i, k)).Value
```

As fixed value:

```
Worksheets("TIME").Range(Cells(j, k)).Value = 1
```

I placed a counter on the loops and they are working properly.

```
On Error Resume Next
Worksheets.Add.Name = "RAW"
Worksheets.Add.Name = "TIME"
Sheets("RAW").Select

'Import and copy data to RAW sheet. It is working so I did not copy it.

Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Select
WidthFile = ActiveCell.Column
Range("A1").End(xlDown).Select
HeightFile = ActiveCell.Row
Range("A1").Select
NumberObs = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ActiveSheet.Range _
              (Cells(1, 1), Cells(HeightFile, 1)), Range("A1").Value)
Sample = Range("A1").Value
j = 1

For i = 2 To HeightFile
    If Range(Cells(i, 1)).Value = Sample Then
        For k = 1 To WidthFile
            Worksheets("TIME").Range(Cells(j, k)).Value = _
                               Range(Cells(i, k)).Value
        Next
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next
```

I expected as import data the rows on RAW Worksheet which first cell it is matching with the first cell on "RAW" Worksheet copied on "TIME" Worksheet. I got a blank worksheet.

The data file I get in RAW Worksheet is like:
[image: RAW DATA]

The expected result on TIME Worksheet should be:
TIME Worksheet expected result sample
[image: TIME DATA]

Comment: I would avoid using `Select` and `Active<Anything>` in your code

Comment: Also to get last row and column I'd go for something like `Dim WidthFile as Long` and then `WidthFile = Range("A1").End(xlRight).Row`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest to work with `Objects` and to use the [With statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/with-statement) when executing several statements on a single object: i.e. use this:

```
With Range("A1")
   WidthFile = .End(xlToRight).Column
   HeightFile= .End(xlDown).Row
End With
```

instead of this:

```
Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Select
WidthFile = ActiveCell.Column
Range("A1").End(xlDown).Select
HeightFile = ActiveCell.Row
```

Also note that [Worksheet.Cells property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.cells) returns a `Range` so use this:

```
.Cells(j, k).Value
```

instead of this:

```
.Range(Cells(j, k)).Value
```

I have done some adjustments to the code you provided. Try this:

```
Sub test()
Dim wsRaw As Worksheet
Dim wsTime As Worksheet
Dim lRows As Long, lCols As Long
Dim lNbrObs As Long, vSample As Variant
Dim j As Long, i As Long, k As Long

    Rem Add these lines after the worksheets had been added
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set wsRaw = .Worksheets("RAW")
        Set wsTime = .Worksheets("TIME")
    End With

    With wsRaw

        lRows = .Cells(1).End(xlDown).Row
        lCols = .Cells(1).End(xlToRight).Column
        vSample = .Cells(1).Value2
        lNbrObs = Application.WorksheetFunction _
            .CountIf(.Cells(1).Resize(lRows), vSample)

        For i = 2 To lRows
            If .Cells(i, 1).Value2 = vSample Then
                j = 1 + j
                For k = 1 To lCols
                    wsTime.Cells(j, k).Value2 = .Cells(i, k).Value2

    Next: End If: Next: End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: Really clean way to do it. Thanks. I already took your idea but still it is not working. On "TIME" worksheet I have no values, it is blank.

Comment: The code in the answer does what is the intention of the code you provided, to ensure the output is what you are expecting, we need to know exactly that *"what is the expected outcome"*. Therefore, please edit your post in order to include a sample of your data in both worksheets indicating the status before and after.